# Problems with accessing server behind a router from the outside world

Tags: networking, router

I have a server that is behind a router. I use port forwarding on some ports to access things like VNC, SSH, etc. However, my router seems to be inaccessible from the outside world. Connections, and even ping time out. My firewall is off, and I don't think there are any special settings that are set differently from the router that the server worked on.

I can strangely ping the router and access the server with the router's IP when connected to the router, but not from the outside world. I also set web and ICMP to LAN and WAN in the "Remote Management" tab.

Any suggestions on what setting etc. is blocking?

---

The router I am using is ZyXEL VMG1312-B30B

Comment: There will undoubtedly be a seeing somewhere to enable remote management of the router. It is more secure, however, to create a VPN server within your LAN that you connect to and then you can remote manage the router as if you were inside the LAN. This will ensure your router remains inaccessible from the outside, as the manufacturer intended.

Comment: Just read your comment that you've already enabled remote management.

Comment: @BigChris In a different case, that would be an ideal solution, but I would like the server to be readily connectable to, without the use of a VPN

Comment: Port forwarding will make the server "readily accessible"...

Comment: So your router is assigned a public ip address or a Carrier NAT address?

Comment: @Ramhound How do I find the difference? Could it be a carrier NAT, if a person on a different LAN, in a similar location can connect, but others can't? Also, my router's IP starts with 10.226, which does not appear to be in the IP range for my country (Czech Republic)